# Http Data Request(app crashes)

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

I am a beginner at Andriod programming,I use android Studio but i saw an Http tutorial online using eclipse which i interpreted best i could in Android studio,The app has an HttpManager class which returns json data shown below

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;


public class HttpManager {


    public static String getData(String uri) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader reader= null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String line;
          while ((line=reader.readLine()) !=null) {

              sb.append(line+ "\n");

          }


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        finally {
            if(reader != null){
                reader.close();
            }
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }


}
```

The main activity particularyly the doInbackground method is supposed to get this json data and display it but the app crashes after the onPrexecute method code below

```
 import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.os.AsyncTaskCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.TextViewCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Policy;
import java.util.Objects;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView output;
    ProgressBar pb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        output=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        output.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        pb= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            if (isOnline()){
                requestData("http://localhost/database/getInfodroid.php");
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Network Unavailable",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void requestData(String uri) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        task.execute(uri);
    }

    protected void updateDisplay(String message){
        output.append(message +"\n");

    }

   protected boolean isOnline(){
       ConnectivityManager cm= (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       NetworkInfo netinfo= cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       if(netinfo!= null && netinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
           return true;
       }
       else {
           return false;
       }



   }


    private class MyTask extends AsyncTask {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            updateDisplay("Background Task Started");
            pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {

            try {
                String content =HttpManager.getData(objects[0].toString());
                return content;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return "Task Complete";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
           updateDisplay(o.toString());
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {
            updateDisplay(values[0].toString());
        }
    }



}
```

I repeat again I am very new and I interpreted it best I could in Android Studio it was slightly different in eclipse,av set all permissions

After changing from localhost to IP adress app doesent crash but i now get following exception
LOGCAT:

```
10-03 14:13:21.876 2126-9411/? W/System.err: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:124)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:452)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:884)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:117)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectRawSocket(SocketConnector.java:160)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectCleartext(SocketConnector.java:67)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:152)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
10-03 14:13:21.877 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
10-03 14:13:21.878 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
10-03 14:13:21.878 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
10-03 14:13:21.878 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:384)
10-03 14:13:21.878 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:231)
10-03 14:13:21.878 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at hilz.myapplication.HttpManager.getData(HttpManager.java:22)
10-03 14:13:21.878 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at hilz.myapplication.MainActivity$MyTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:118)
10-03 14:13:21.884 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
10-03 14:13:21.884 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-03 14:13:21.901 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
10-03 14:13:21.901 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
10-03 14:13:21.901 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
10-03 14:13:21.902 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-03 14:13:21.902 2126-9411/? W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
10-03 14:13:21.902 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
10-03 14:13:21.906 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:111)
10-03 14:13:21.906 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
10-03 14:13:21.908 2126-9411/? W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
10-03 14:13:21.908 2126-9411/? W/System.err:    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Can you post your logcat output so we know what is throwing the error?

Comment: http://localhost/database/getInfodroid.php -> I don't think you want localhost here as it will be the device localhost not your PC.  I bet you need to change localhost to the IP address of the server.

Comment: How could i solve this it appears to not connect to server now but app doesent crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found what i was looking for right here on stackoverflow,Apparently i was supposed to use 10.0.2.2 as opposed to using localhost in my url code

Answer (score 0):

The object received in onPostExecute is null, sow calling to your updateDisplay(...) it's throwing a NPE.

I recommend you to save "content" as an attribute and retrieve the value on your postExecute method.

I recommend you once to be careful trying to update the UI not in your main thread (postexecute comes after a background task).

Take a look:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask {

private Activity activity;
private String content;

public MyTask(Activity activity){this.activity = activity;}

 @Override
 protected void onPreExecute() {
   updateDisplay("Background Task Started");
   pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }

 @Override
 protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
   try {
       content =HttpManager.getData(objects[0].toString());
       return content;
   } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return "Task Complete";
 }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateDisplay(content);
            pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);     
        }
    });    

 }

 @Override
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Object[] values) {
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          updateDisplay(values[0].toString());
        }
    });  
 }
}
```

I hope this would help you.

Comment: This answer is my first guess because I haven't got your stacktrace... I usually specify running on main thread in case of any doubt

Comment: This isn't my question, I was just letting you know. But yeah without his stack trace it's hard to tell

Comment: You can find interesting this component for making httpRequests: https://github.com/juaagugui/AndroidHttpRestService . it's easy to learn and be used. It's mine, and I add it to all my projects

Comment: oops, sorry @user1282637. Too late here in Spain to correctly read. :P

Comment: Ok thanks guys will post the log cat once I get a better Internet connection I will also follow your suggestions and I will give u back the feedback by tomorrow night

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think it's an error after the execution. I hope being helpful

Comment: Michael sorry for late reply had andrid studio issues,so i tried out your suggestion,and now the app doesent crash but i get the following exception

Comment: Please. Mark the answer as correct in case it is for rewarding the spent time. You can open another one for this new issue.

Answer (score 0):

10.0.2.2 is the local host of the emulator, meaning if your have a test server on your PC that you are running the emulator on. If that is not the case it will not solve your problem. If you are pretty sure it's the IP, I would just explore your network options and get your PC's IP. Making the IP that of your servers will also allow you to USB test it from devices, not just the emulator.

Looking at the code, I don't see a declared method (POST/GET) if you are sending data from your app to the server. The URL you sent has no parameters in it either, so unless the specific page has encoded objects for you to return already, you will get another error.

Here is an example script I use to connect to a server

```
public class CCJson {

    // left blank to aviod calls to this constructor
    public CCJson(){}
    // place your IP in place of the ip
    public static String url = "http://102.0.0.1/appActions.php";


    public static JSONObject performPostCallObj( String params) throws MalformedURLException {

        URL defURL = new URL(url);
        JSONObject response=null;
        try {


            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) defURL.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter( conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(params);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            String line;
            StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                response =new JSONObject(sb.toString());
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

I call this code from an AsyncTask and it returns an JSONObject